# Re-routing on shared host in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

The basic problem is that default site/index is working for local host but not for shared host.I have looked into a lot of things but couldn't find the solution.Also other controllers like orders/index is working. Please help.

Comment: show me the url you or the code for create the url that you are using for accessing to  the site/index

Comment: its a shared host(192.168.10.x) and I have made a virtual host on this with the document root for the same as var/www/html/jd4/web , after this if I enter orders/index it is working but not with site/index @scaisEdge

Answer (score 0):

While using shared host it is important to check`'urlManager'=>['rules'= array()]`. Make sure you are following those rules.